# React Game of Life fails silently, what am I missing?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

**SITUATION:**

I am currently learning React. As an exercise, I am trying to code Conway's Game of Life:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conway%27s_Game_of_Life

Here are the rules:

- "Any live cell with fewer than two live neighbours dies, as if caused
  by underpopulation.
- Any live cell with two or three live neighbours lives on to the next 
  generation.
- Any live cell with more than three live neighbours dies, as if by
  overpopulation
- Any dead cell with exactly three live neighbours becomes a live cell,
  as if by reproduction."

So, I started coding a skeleton based on tutorials and explanations I found online while coding it my way.

I got to a point where normally the cells should behave as expected, but nothing happens:

I click on the board to create some cells, press Start and they have no life of their own :/

They don't die and reproduce, nothing happens.

No error anywhere to guide me !

What may I have done wrong ?

[image]

---

**CODE:**

```
    var Game = createReactClass ({

        getInitialState() {
            return {
                start: false
            }
        },

        handleStartClick() {
            this.setState({
                start: true
            })
        },

        handleClearClick() {
            this.setState({
                start: false
            })
        },

        render() {
            return (
                <div>
                    <h1>React.js Game of Life</h1>
                    <div className="buttons"> 
                        <button className="btn btn-danger" onClick={this.handleClearClick}>Clear</button>
                        <button className="btn btn-success" onClick={this.handleStartClick}>Start</button>
                    </div>
                    <Board start={this.state.start}/>
                </div>
            );
        }

    })

var Board = createReactClass ({

    getInitialState() {
        return {
            array: []
        }
    },

    render() {

        var rows = [];
        for (var y = 1; y <= 40; y++) {
            var cells = [];
            for (var x = 1; x <= 40; x++) {
                cells.push(<Cell start= {this.props.start} array={this.state.array} key={x + x*y} id = {x + x*y} />);
            }
            rows.push(<tr key={y}>{cells}</tr>);
        }
        return <table><tbody>{rows}</tbody></table>;

    }

})

var Cell = createReactClass ({

    getInitialState() {
        return {
            selected : false,
            dying: false
        }
    },

    isAlive(e) {
        return e.state.selected
    },

    componentDidMount() {

        this.props.array[this.props.id] = this;

        var life;
        var evolution;

        if(this.props.start) {
            life = setInterval(function(){ 
                this.life;
            }, 500);
            evolution = setInterval(function(){ 
                this.setState({
                    selected: !this.state.dying
                });
            }, 1000);
        } 
        else {
            clearInterval(life);
            clearInterval(evolution);
        }
    },

    life() {

        var array = this.props.array;

        var neighbours = 0;

        if (this.isAlive(array[this.props.id+1])) {
            neighbours++;
        }
        if (this.isAlive(array[this.props.id-1])) {
            neighbours ++;
        }
        if (this.isAlive(array[this.props.id-39])) {
            neighbours ++;
        }
        if (this.isAlive(array[this.props.id-40])) {
            neighbours ++;
        }
        if (this.isAlive(array[this.props.id-41])) {
            neighbours ++;
        }
        if (this.isAlive(array[this.props.id+41])) {
            neighbours ++;
        }
        if (this.isAlive(array[this.props.id+40])) {
            neighbours ++;
        }
        if (this.isAlive(array[this.props.id+39])) {
            neighbours ++;
        }

        if (this.state.selected) {
            if (neighbours == 3 || neighbours == 2) {
                this.setState({
                    dying: false
                })
            }
            else if (neighbours < 2) {
                this.setState({
                    dying: true
                })
            }
            else if (neighbours > 3) {
                this.setState({
                    dying: true
                })
            }
        }
        else {
            if( neighbours == 3) {
                this.setState({
                    dying : false
                })
            }
        }
    },

    handleClick() {
        this.setState({
            selected: !this.state.selected
        })
    },

    render() {
        return <td onClick = {this.handleClick} className={this.state.selected ? "cell selected" : "cell"}></td>;
    }
})

ReactDOM.render(<Game />, document.getElementById('gameOfLife'));
```

Comment: Where are you attaching this component? `ReactDOM.render(<Game />...)`?

Comment: @adam-beck Forgot to add it to my SO question. Thx !

Comment: What I would do is start removing stuff until you find the problem. For instance, remove `<Board />` from the `render()` function of Game and see if anything shows up on the screen.

Comment: @adam-beck As pointed in my question, everything shows up. It's just that the dots don't evolve.

Comment: Sorry :( I must've missed that part.

Comment: are you expecting one single evolution? If you press start what is supposed to happen? Usually with GOL it is a runaway process, ie. a thread where many evolutions happen

Comment: @OliverWatkins I expect my setIntervals to be triggered, so yes: a runaway process :)

Comment: @adam-beck np :D

Comment: have you tried putting break points in your componentWillMount fn? Is the interval fn being called after 2 seconds?

Comment: @OliverWatkins Actually, I just started logging a bit, and I found that the setIntervals are never triggered. Also, my implementation of steps seems pretty wrong. I would need to reimplement a way to generate steps based on time, but idk how.

Comment: Michael's answer should fix the problem of `setInterval`s not triggering. You'll also need to handle `this` differently because inside the `setTimeout` callback it will point to the global object.

Comment: Here's a pen that could be helpful for quick testing and troubleshooting: https://codepen.io/Kaivosukeltaja/pen/BRKbxe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`componentDidMount`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#componentwillmount) only fires when the component initially mounts.  When the `start` flag switched from `false` to `true` it is not firing again to start the intervals.

You should use [`componentWillReceiveProps`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#componentwillreceiveprops) instead as this fires every time the props change.

**Note**: I wont guarantee this will make your game work, just that the intervals will start running so you can continue to debug your work.

Comment: Your reasoning is correct. Now my setIntervals are called and I get: Cannot read property 'dying' of undefined... Hmmm

Comment: Changing to ComponentDidUpdate makes everything work without error, except that the only thing happening is the entire grid getting filled with living cells...

Comment: Yeah as `Kaivosukeltaja` mentioned in the other comment chain, `this` won't work in the `setTimeout` callback.

Comment: Hmmm, fixed that, now I can put dots, but they disappear whatever happens... hmmm

Comment: `ComponentDidUpdate` is a bad idea as this will fire every time the component updates, including when the you call `setState`.  so you will be triggering tons of additional intervals.

Comment: I need to put the setIntervals somewhere else, and probably use them differently also, but I don't know how :/ Everything becomes so confusing in React for me. In vanilla js, it wouldn't take me 30 minutes to do this. Grrr, learning :/

Comment: With `componentWillReceiveProps` , I need to click twice on Start for the simulation to begin

Comment: you need to change all the references of `this.props` to be `nextProps` (as a parameter to the function)

Comment: I think this question has run it's course as it's starting to turn into an extended debugging session.   We got you over the hurdle you were stuck at and now you need to step back and look at the problem again with the new knowledge you have.  Feel free to add new questions for the specific issue you run into (after sufficient research of course).  I also feel like I did answer the initial problem laid out in the question and would appreciate an accepted answer, but if you do not feel the same I understand.

Comment: Here is your due, Sir.